# Solving a simple system of partial differential equations in closed form

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, quadratics, differential

I have the following system of partial differential equations -

$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} = c_1(x^2+y^2) - c_2$$
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} = c_1((x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2) - c_2$$

How do I go about solving these in closed form? If I try to naively integrate them, then the first one will involve $x^3$ while the second one will involve $y^3$.

Comment: Have you tried doing that? Is there a problem?

Comment: The only direction I could think of was to integrate them. If I do that, I get an $x^3$ term in f(x,y) from the first equation and a $y^3$ term from the second one. Not sure how to reconcile them. Beyond this, I'm stuck.

Comment: They don't need to be reconciled. When you integrate the first with respect to $x$, the constant is a function in $y$ (why?).

Comment: Because it's like taking a slice along a plane where $y$ is constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

We get:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}f(x,y)=c_1\frac{x^3}{3}+c_1y^2x-c_2x+g(y)\\
f(x,y)=c_1y(x-x_1)^2+c_1\frac{(y-y_1)^3}{3}-c_2y+h(x)
\end{array}\right.$$

then $c_1=0$ (why?),   and  $g(y)=-c_2y$,
 and $h(x)=-c_2x$

If $c_1 \neq 0 $ then there is no solution.

If $c_1=0$  then  $f(x,y)=-c_2(x+y)$

Comment: Hmm, quite disappointing that if $c_1\neq 0$, there is no solution.

Comment: Yes , but it's true because derivating with y we get: $g'(y)+2c_1y=c_1(x-x_1)^2+c_1(y-y_1)^2-c_2$ thus: $g'(y)+2c_1y-c_1(y-y_1)^2+c_2=c_1(x-x_1)^2=0$